# Use kubernetes with helm and provide my predefined user and password with bitnami correctly

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I am using kubernetes with helm 3.

I need to create a kubernetes pod with sql - creating:

> database name: my_database
> user: root
> password:12345
> port: 3306

The steps:
creating chart by:

```
helm create test
```

after the chart is created, change the Chart.yaml file in test folder, by adding dependencies section.

> apiVersion: v2
> name: test3
> description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
>
> version: 0.1.0
>
> appVersion: "1.16.0"
>
> dependencies:
>
> - name: mysql
>   version: 8.8.23   repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"

run:

```
helm dependencies build test
```

After that there is a compressed file `tgz`.
So I extracted it and there is tar file - I extracted it too, and leave only the final extracted folder.

I presume this isn't the best approach of changing parameter in `yaml` for `bitnami`,
and using also the `security.yaml` - I would like knowing that better approach too.

I need to change the user + password, and link to database,
so I changed the values.yaml directly (any better approach?), for values: auth:rootPassword and auth:my_database.

the another following steps:

```
helm build dependencies test
helm install test --namespace test --create-namespace
```

after that there are two pods created.
I could check it by:

```
kubectl get pods -n test
```

and I see two pods running (maybe replication).
one of the pod: test-mysql-0 (the other is with random parse).

run:

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty test-mysql-0  --namespace test-mysql -- /bin/sh
```

did enter the pod.
run:

```
mysql -rroot -p12345;
```

and then:

```
show databases;
```

That did showing all the database, including seeing the created database: my_database, successfully.

When I tried openning the `mysql` database from 'mysql workbench', and test (same user: root, and password, and port: 3306, and localhost), I couldn't run test (test connection button in database properties returns: 'failed to connect to database').

1. Why cannot I run properly 'mysql workbench', while in the pad itself - without any particular problem?
2. Is there any better approach than extrating the tgz file as I described above, and can I pass in better way (some secured yaml) the user+password?
   (Right now is only the root password)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to set the parameters in the dependent chart (please correct me if I'm wrong)

If this is right, all you need to do is add another section in *your* chart's `values.yaml`

```yaml
name-of-dependency:
  user-name: ABC
  password: abcdef
```

the "name-of-dependency" is specified in your `Chart.yaml` file when you declare your chart. For example, here's my redis dependency from one of my own charts

```yaml
dependencies:
  - name: redis
    repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami/
    version: x.x.x
```

Then when I install the chart, I can override the redis chart's settings by doing this in my own chart's `values.yaml`

```yaml
redis:
  architecture: standalone
  auth:
    password: "secret-password-here"
```

Comment: OK. Thank you. That works fine. No need to extract the compressed file!

For my other question - why cannot I enter the mysql by workbench? 
Also, I rather prefer using the secret.yaml file instead of passing the user+password in yaml.

Thank you.

Comment: You would need to expose the service. If you're using the bitnami MySQL chart, you need to set the value `primary.service.type` from ClusterIP to LoadBalancer to get an external IP for the service, which you can then use in workbench. Details of other settings are available on their artifacthub page: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/mysql

Comment: Great!!! Thank you! That primary.service.type change solve another problem!
Last thing - about the secret (I don't wan't to put the real user+password in the files, but encrypt them somehow) - How can I do that?

Comment: Because the chart requires those values as parameters during the install/update, these have to be in the clear during that time. You _could_ do something like have it stored encrypted in the repo, then pass it decrypted during the install during a CI/CD pipeline, using credentials the only CI/CD has access to. So something like `helm install my-chart --set mysql.auth.username=$(decrypt-with-ci-credentials encrypted.username) --set mysql.auth.password=$(decrypt-with-ci-credentials encrypted.password)`.

Comment: Also, try not to use something like helm's `--debug` switch or using `bash -x` with this (unless you are debugging), otherwise, the credentials then become visible.

Comment: @BlenderBox if I am using mysql 5.6 (not bitnami). How can I access mysql via workbench.

Comment: @Eitan you need to set whatever switches are needed on the chart you are using such that it creates and external balancer -- then you use the IP from the loadbalancer service from your workbench. The chart _may_ have this set by default.